# Replace special characters with VBA

Tags: vba, special-characters

I'm trying to replace romanian characters (like "șțȘȚ") from an Excel file using VBA, but I can't figure it out.

In the VBA editor, if I try to type "ș" or "ț" it is replaced by "?". Why???

I even tryed a different approach like:

```html
Selection.Replace What:="&#351;", Replacement:="s", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

but it does absolutelly nothing...
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tried a quick solution for ș which has the ascii code 351. So it could be described with

```
ChrW(351)
```

So here is my code:

```
Sub replance()

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Worksheets(1).Columns("A:G")

rng.Replace What:=ChrW(351), Replacement:="s", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks good except for terminology. ChrW takes a UTF-16 code unit. UTF-16 is an encoding of the Unicode character set. The characters in question each need one UTF-16 code unit. Hex would be the preferred base because you could directly map the code unit &H15F to the codepoint [U+015F](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/015f/index.htm)(ş).

Comment: What function can be used for Hex?